# Stand alone "SEO Smart Links" plugin functionality

Tags: php, hyperlink, keyword

Anybody can provide code snippet how to implement something like "SEO Smart Links" does ?

Here is what it does:  SEO Smart Links can automatically link keywords and phrases in your posts and comments with corresponding posts, pages, categories and tags on your blog.

So e.g. I will provide array of keywords + links, pass it to the function and function must search for those words in post and then replace them and create links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) (click on the link to RTM) can give you what you are looking for.  This is a PHP function that takes a string, looks for any given string in that string, and replaces it with another string.  It has full regular expression support.